# sh steps in Jenkins pipeline fails when '&' is part of the URL

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I need to download an artifact from Nexus and I am using wget and calling it from sh resource of pipeline

```
def artifact_url = nexus_url + '?r=company-group&g=com.oa&a=test&v=' + version + '&p=war'
sh (script : "wget ${artifact_url} -O earfile.ear")
```

The above code fails as the pipeline is unable to append anything to the URL which has an ampersand in front of it. The output from the error is given below

```
[V2_DEPLOY] Running shell script
+ g=com.oa
+ a=earapp
+ p=war
+ -O earfile.ear
+ v=99.005.08-SNAPSHOT
+ wget 'https://nexus/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=group-repo'
/WORKSPACE PATH/script.sh: line 2: -O: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved after I wrapped the URL around single quotes

```
sh (script : "wget '${artifact_url}' -O earfile.ear")
```